# Why can vector be declared public but not queue

Tags: python, cython

Cython allows to declare a vector from the c++ standard library as public but not a queue, why is that?

```
# distutils: language = c++

from libcpp.vector cimport vector
from libcpp.queue cimport queue

cdef class MyClass
    
    cdef public vector[int] var1
    cdef public queue[int] var2
```

When trying to build an extension - `setup(ext_modules = cythonize('filename.pyx', language_level='3'))` - it throws these errors:

```
C attribute of type 'queue[int]' cannot be accessed from Python
Cannot convert 'queue[int]' to Python object
Cannot convert Python object to 'queue[int]'
```

But it works if `public` is removed. The reason it even matters is the code runs a bit faster when a variable that is used frequently and accessed from different functions in the class is declared public compared to when it isn't.

So it is strange that one class from the c++ stdlib can be public but not another, why is that?

Comment: "The reason it even matters is the code runs a bit faster when a variable that is used frequently and accessed from different functions in the class is declared public compared to when it isn't." - that really doesn't sound right. I think you may be seeing random timing fluctuations, execution order effects, or some other cause of timing variation and misattributing the effects to `public`.

Comment: The error tells you all you need to know:there is no automatic conversion from queue to a python object, but there is one for vector. Public members can be accessed from python and thus there must be a conversion to python available

Comment: I see. Appears there is also automatic conversion for list, set, pair, and map, but not for stack, deque, or queue.

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that the auto-conversion will do you no favours here: any modifications you make to the auto-converted list will not be propagated to the vector.